# Generating Doxygen documentation for C++ STL headers

Tags: c++, c++14, doxygen, gnu

Trying to generate Doxygen output for GNU C++ STL headers (located in `/usr/include/c++/6/` directory). It kind of works, it generates the output but the result is rather meager - no documentation generated for, for example, std::vector public functions etc. The header file functions look properly annotated but still can't get the desired output.

Tried tweaking numerous entries in Doxyfile (RECURSIVE, EXTRACT_ALL, etc) but no joy.
Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
$ doxygen --version
1.8.13
```

As an example, the annotation for std::vector::swap() function looks like:

```
 /**
  *  @brief  Swaps data with another %vector.
  *  @param  __x  A %vector of the same element and allocator types.
  *
  *  This exchanges the elements between two vectors in constant time.
  *  (Three pointers, so it should be quite fast.)
  *  Note that the global std::swap() function is specialized such that
  *  std::swap(v1,v2) will feed to this function.
  */
void
swap(vector& __x) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
{
     //....
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to know which version of doxygen you are using and also an example of, part of, the mentioned problem / file for those that don't have that file.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I wanted to include an image.

I took the code as indicated, a plain Doxyfile with only `EXTRACT_ALL` set to `YES` and I get:

[image]

I might overlook something, but this looks OK to me.
If I overlooked something please indicate it in the original question as an edit.

- what is the filename you used?

Some side remarks:

- current doxygen version is 1.8.15
- have also a look at the chapter "Preprocessing" for `_GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT`

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an "official" means of generating this documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/documentation_hacking.html

If nothing else, you could grab a GCC package and look at what Doxygen file it has, and then re-purpose that so it looks in your system header directory.  There are a lot of preprocessor macros in the headers, so likely Doxygen is getting tripped up on these.